Позиция мыши в трапеции js
Не получается перевести координаты мыши на странице в координаты на квадрате под наклоном по оси X на 33 градуса через css свойство transform: rotateX(33deg). Заранее спасибо.

Вам нужны перспективные преобразования (не аффинные)

Да, я создаю шахматную доску под перспективой и нужно получить координаты мыши внутри неё.

Вам нужно найти библиотеку для перспективных преобразований, оттуда понадобится функция маппинга (которая рассчитывает матрицу ПП) прямоугольника на произвольный четырехугольник и наоборот. Пример на cpp https://www.rsdn.org/forum/src/461771.1, про js я не в курсе, но такое точно существует

@MBo, там же матрица преобразования остается
